# How fix/change css background color around the edge by full screen mode?

Tags: html, css, colors, fancybox, fullscreen

How fix/change css background color around the edge by full screen mode?
Where there is a camera, the color of the white background. I need a default black color.

[where there is a front camera, the color of the white background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHYGY.jpg)

::fullscren and ::backdrop didn't help...

code to switch to fullscreen mode:

```
          var goFullScreen = null;
          var exitFullScreen = null;
          if ('requestFullscreen' in document.documentElement) {
            goFullScreen = 'requestFullscreen';
            exitFullScreen = 'exitFullscreen';
          } else if ('mozRequestFullScreen' in document.documentElement) {
            goFullScreen = 'mozRequestFullScreen';
            exitFullScreen = 'mozCancelFullScreen';
          } else if ('webkitRequestFullscreen' in document.documentElement) {
            goFullScreen = 'webkitRequestFullscreen';
            exitFullScreen = 'webkitExitFullscreen';
          } else if ('msRequestFullscreen') {
            goFullScreen = 'msRequestFullscreen';
            exitFullScreen = 'msExitFullscreen';
          }


document.documentElement[goFullScreen] && document.documentElement[goFullScreen]();
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.

Comment: For example, this [site] (https://whatwebcando.today/screen-orientation) has switched to fullscreen mode, if you turn the screen to landscape and click the full screen button, the background around the camera will be black (my camera is located in a droplet and occupies part of the screen). In my fullscreen mode, fancybox shows a bright white color, not the default black. it's only on mobile.

Comment: it does not depend on fancybox, always when you switch to full-screen mode, there is a white background around the camera

Comment: as I understand it, with a full-screen mode, the status bar is painted white... hm

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, it’s unclear if this will work: try creating a `div` and using CSS, assign it `absolute` positioning with 100% `width` and `height`. You can assign it a `background-color`. Within your conditionals, you could toggle the `visibility` attribute of the `div` to `hidden` or `visible` depending on when exiting or entering full screen, respectively. You’d need to address the `z-index` of the div to properly layer it behind the full screen content.

Comment: Inspecting the elements created by toggling full screen might give better insight on styling currently applied.